# Searching a probability distribution by observation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a ballot box containing $n\in\mathbb{N}$ colored balls.
By extracting $0<k<n$ of those denote that they are all white.

Which is the probability that $k+1$-th ball is white?

Comment: what is the starting distribution of white balls in the ballot box to begin with

Comment: It is unknown. You can turn the question by asking which is the probability that the sentence "the $k+1$-th ball would be white" is wrong.